# Is it safe to execute update during paged select in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

Assume we make a paged select from some table. Is it safe to execute update statement on the same data while retrieving it, given that updates will never add new or remove old rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, perfectly safe, in terms of nothing bad will happen. Keep in mind your response is not in isolated, saved or anything. If data from when you started to do your read, the paging might return data thats been updated.

Everything can be handled concurrently though. If using paxos and updating the same partition a ton you might get some contention slowdowns, but for normal operations theres nothing to worry about.

Comment: "If data from when you started to do your read, the paging might return data thats been updated." - this is basically what I'm interested in. I'm iterating over table rows and modify some of them. Won't I get into situation when some rows aren't received or some modified rows appear twice in select?

Comment: they wont ever appear twice because of the way paging works. If you modify something at exact same time as paging though its hard to know if your going to get the old value or new value.